# Problem creating forgot password functionality in node js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I created a user registration and login form using mongoose, passport and passport-local in node. But now I am finding it difficult to create forgot password functionality. I want a user to reset their password just by entering their username and the new password in the forgot password page.

Comment: *What* problem have you had creating it? Also note that is a very insecure implementation, there's no point having passwords if the only thing you need to know to reset them is the username.

Comment: Their username and other details